# Stick ID to the HTML element (using js) instead of id-attribute?

Tags: javascript, html

First post on stackoverflow. Hope everything is right!

I'm thinking of attaching an ID value to the HTML element itself via JavaScript, instead of using the HTML `id` attribute.

For instance, say that JavaScript variable `htmlElement` is a div. So `htmlElement.cssName` would tell us its CSS class.

Now, how about doing

```
htmlElement.idProperty = "someValue"
```

in JavaScript instead of doing `<div id="someValue">`? Then I can use the `idProperty` in say event handlers.

```
this.idProperty
```

That simple!

Is there something wrong in doing so?

EDIT: Thanks for yor answers! Very helpful and instructive. I wish I could check green on all of them!

Comment: Note that it's className, not cssName; other HTMLElement attributes are accessed using their regular names, so just "id" is correct.  See http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-HTML/html.html#ID-95362176 for background.

Comment: It feels a bit semantically wrong to add and remove id-elements. An identity isn't really identity if it comes and goes.  Have you looked into toggling classes on the element instead if dynamic css-styling is your goal? jQuery/* makes it really simple to toggle classes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**no**, you can do it the way you like it, if you are dynamically creating this item you should use this method, if you are doing this inside html I recommend you to just put the name of the id in html too.

However a small note. Use element.id instead of idProperty.

```
element.id = 'my-id';
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`createAttribute`](http://www.zvon.org/xxl/DOM2reference/Output/Core/method_createAttribute_Document.html) method to add an `id` to the element like this:

```
id = document.createAttribute('id');
id.value = "someValue";
htmlElement.setAttributeNode(id);
```

Comment: I prefer using `setAttribute`: `htmlElement.setAttribute("id", "someValue");` - http://www.w3.org/TR/2000/WD-DOM-Level-1-20000929/level-one-core.html#ID-F68F082

Answer (score 0):

What you're doing there is adding a runtime property (in your case, called `idProperty`) to an `HTMLElement` object instance. You **can** get away with doing that in your JavaScript code (the [Prototype](http://prototypejs.org) library does it all the time). Makes me uncomfortable, but it does work on all major browsers.

If you want to be able to specify these in HTML markup as well, though, I'd use attributes instead. You can create attributes with any names you want, although to be careful I'd use names like `data-xyz` (e.g., use a `data-` prefix) as that's the HTML5 standard way of using your own attributes. Then you use `getAttribute` to get the value and `setAttribute` to set/update the value.